# Replace first character inside the label

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change each labels first character except the last labels character $ sign to £ using jQuery?

Here is the code:

```
<p align="center" id="myradio">
    <label>$25.00 </label>
    <input checked="checked" class="hide_input" name="amount" type="radio" value="25.00" />
    <label>$50.00</label>
    <input class="hide_input" name="amount" type="radio" value="50.00" />
    <label>$100.00</label>
    <input class="hide_input" name="amount" type="radio" value="100.00" />
    <label>$250.00</label>
    <input class="hide_input" name="amount" type="radio" value="250.00" />
    <label>$500.00</label>
    <input class="hide_input" name="amount" type="radio" value="500.00" />
    <label>$1000.00</label>
    <input class="hide_input" name="amount" type="radio" value="1000.00" />
    <label>other amount</label>
    <input class="show_input" id="other" name="amount" type="radio" value="" />
</p>
```

Comment: Your last label doesn't have any instance of the $ sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myradio label').html(function() {
   return this.innerHTML.replace(/^\$/,'£');
});
```

Comment: This replaces the end of the string with the new character, since `$/` signifies the end of a value in regular expressions. You would need to escape the dollar sign to handle it as a literal.

Comment: No problem. It was a one-char mistake that anybody could make. Keep up the great work.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the internal looping to swap the characters:

```
$("#myradio label").html(function(){
    return this.innerHTML.replace( '$', '£' ); 
});
```

Comment: That's pretty slick, I have to say. +1

Comment: I finally did something like this.
    <code>$("#myradio label:not(:last), #setlabelright, label").html(function(){
    return this.innerHTML.replace( '£', '$' );
    });</code>

Comment: @user1235905 read more about [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). `#myradio label:not(:last)` will be included in `label`. you may search for the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#myradio label:not(:last)").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/^\$/, "£"));
});
```

Comment: No need to run an explicit loop using `$.each` when this is done internally.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Yes but you can only do this internally since jQuery 1.4

Comment: jQuery 1.4 was released in [January of 2010](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/01/14/jquery-14-released/), over 2 years ago. I don't think we need to be worried about coding against 1.4 unless the OP specifically requests it.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I don't program that long, so I did not knew this. Btw your answer is perfect, I just recommend you to use this selector `#myradio label:not(:last)` because user1235905 has asked in his question to do not include the last label.

Comment: No worries; your answer isn't *wrong*. It's just a performance issue :) Also, regarding the last element, I didn't bother since there are no dollar signs in "other amount". Still waiting on the OP to answer the comment I left on the question though. Keep up the great work!

Answer (score 2):

```
    $('#myradio label').each(function() {
       $(this).text('£' + $(this).text().substr(1));
    });
```

This basically takes the substring of the label, beginning from the first character (till the end) - which is the text without the $ symbol. And appends it to the pound symbol. This concatenated text is used tot replace the existing text.

Comment: You should try to explain your answer as well, even if you think it is self explanatory - others may not. Just doing some http://stackoverflow.com/review/, did not mod down.